# jQuery Address do not work in callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-address, swfaddress

Today I explored something weird: jQuery Address do not work in jQuery callbacks:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wh7uS/19/
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding to the init event of the address, which is triggered before the callback.
You can see that if you change the fadein timer to 0:

```
$("#second").fadeIn(0, function() {

jQuery.address.init(function(event) {
    alert("jQuery Address - inside");
});
alert("Sorry for the many alerts");
});
```

It's callback will run immediately, binding the init event handler which will be invoked and shoot of the alert (all from in the callback). Timing is everything :)

Answer (score 0):

change jquery to `jquery <1.6` and things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that?  http://jsfiddle.net/Wh7uS/18/

Comment: I looking for way to work how have to be, or maybe is impossible. This link is my old way to show the problem.